# Make a specific option disappear in the second drop down based on the selected option in the first drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am creating a two drop down list that has same value. The first drop down is **Flight_From** and the second drop down is **Flight_To**, every time the user clicks an option from the first drop down (**Flight_From**), the second dropdown (**Flight_To**) should **disable or hide** the same value that is currently selected from the first drop down.

**Illustration:**

[image]

**Example from the picture:**

I chose "Legazpi" from the first Dropdown while in the second Dropdown the option "Legazpi" disappeared.

**Current Code**

```
<select name="flying_from" id = "flying_from" onchange="val()" class="form-control @error('flying_from') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('flying_from') }}" required autocomplete="flying_from" autofocus>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
        @foreach($countries as $country)
             <option value="{{$country->country_id}}">{{$country->country_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>

<script type="application/javascript">

    function val() {
        fly_from_selected_option = document.getElementById("flying_from").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("flying_to").options[fly_from_selected_option].disabled = true;
    }
```

In this snippet code I can currently only get the index of the selected option from the first drop down (**Flight_From**)

> **Question:**
>
> How to disable or hide the option that is selected from the first drop
>   down (**Flight_From**) in the second drop down (**Flight_To**)?

Comment: What have you already tried? What is your data structure? This really needs more clarification.

Comment: use this plugin - https://select2.org/options

Comment: Are you using native html5 select ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI yes and I am using latest version of bootstrap

Comment: Can you post sample code that you have tried so far

Comment: @AkhilAravind I updated my post and Included my code now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
$('#flyingFromDropDownId').change(function() {        
    value = this.value;
    $("#flyingToDropDownId option[value!='" + value + "']").show();
    $("#flyingToDropDownId option[value='" + value + "']").hide();                                               
});
```

Check Working [Repl](https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/IllfatedFrillyArea)

Comment: It gives me an error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange